# Recognize a word in an audio file

Tags: listening

I'm not sure what the taxi driver is saying in this [audio file](http://79.175.174.232/content/lessons/11/Intermediate1_2/unit%204/listening/listening.mp3), number 5:

> Do you want to ... a cab

What does he say before `a cab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he says:

Do you want to order a cab to pick you up at the airport when you get back?
I can do that for you if you like.